# Yii Mailer PHP Error Array to string conversion

Tags: php, arrays, yii, string-conversion

The problem is the checkboxlist selection which is a multiple select. When I remove the following mailer code from the controller, the form is emailed... `'{serviceItem}' => $model->selection,`

In the model, the following explode and implode is used for putting the selection into the db table correctly...

```
public function afterFind()
{

    $this->selection=explode(',',$this->selection);

        return true;

}

/*implode your selection */
public function beforeSave()
{
    $this->selection=implode(',',$this->selection);
        return true;


}
```

If implode beforeSave...

> [quote="php manual"] Returns a string containing a string
>   representation of all the array elements in the same order, with the
>   glue string between each element.[/quote]

And the mailer `$message = strtr` returns a string from the array...

> [quote="phpmanual"]strtr - If given two arguments, the second should be an array in the
>   form array('from' => 'to', ...). The return value is a string where all the occurrences of
>   the array keys have been replaced by the corresponding values...

```
$message = strtr ('Submitted on: {submissionDate}
Name: {firstName} {lastName}

Service Item: {serviceItem}

Visitor Comments: {message}', array(
'{submissionDate}' => $model->date,
'{firstName}' => $model->firstName,
'{lastName}' => $model->lastName,

'{serviceItem}' => $model->selection,

'{message}' => $model->comments));
```

Q. Why is there an error? and...

Q. **What is the solution for the $model->selections to be sent in the email?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Q. Why is there an error?

#### Answer:

First `strtr()` expects the array to be of the form `array('stringFROM'=>'stringTO')` and not `array('stringFROM'=>array(...))`.

You are getting the second format(*and hence the error*) because `$model->selection` is an array, since you have done an `explode()` in `afterFind()`.

[`afterFind()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#afterFind-detail) is called whenever you load a model with any of the `find` methods of CActiveRecord(i.e `find()`, `findAll()`, `findByPk()`, `findByAttributes()`, and so on), and if i am correct you are calling one of those of methods to get your current model.

---

> Q. What is the solution for the $model->selections to be sent in the email?

#### Answer:

In this case you can simply do an `implode()` again, to get a string:

```
'{serviceItem}' => implode(',',$model->selection);
```

Comment: you are welcome, i'm glad i could help. consider reading the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) and also [this meta post about accepting answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). no hurries, just informing you of how the community works.

Comment: well now you know! as and when you gain more rep, you'll get more privileges, like voting, commenting anywhere, etc. btw, welcome to s.o, hope you have a good experience here.